# How to print the contents of moving average horizontally in Java

Tags: java, arrays, beacon, rssi

I would like to print the content of the moving average value of Rssi for one particular beacon in Java horizontally. The window period size is 10. However, using this code it printed the result vertically in logcat. Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks

```
 for (Map.Entry < String, ArrayList < Float >> Beaconss: BeaconRssWrtId.entrySet()) {
   List < Float > NewArray;
   List < Float > ArrayOfRss = Beaconss.getValue();
   if (ArrayOfRss.size() < 10) //WindowSize
   {
     NewArray = ArrayOfRss;
   } else
     NewArray = ArrayOfRss.subList(ArrayOfRss.size() - 10, ArrayOfRss.size()); //WIndowSize
   float sum1 = 0;
   float sum2 = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < NewArray.size(); i++) {
     sum1 = sum1 + NewArray.get(i);

   }
   float avg1 = sum1 / NewArray.size(); //Moving average
   MovingAvg.put(Beaconss.getKey(), avg1); //It contains Estimated RSS using Moving Average

   Log.d("MovingAverage", String.valueOf(MovingAvg.get("1")));
```

Comment: This does not appear to be Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Add this above the  for loop:

`String rssiLine = "";`

Replace this line:

`Log.d("MovingAverage", String.valueOf(MovingAvg.get("1")));`

With:

`rssiLine += (String.valueOf(MovingAvg.get("1"))+'');`

Then add this line to the end of the for loop:

`Log.d("MovingAverage", rssiLine);`